# What comes after quintessence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

1. Singularity
2. Duplicity
3. Triplicity
4. Quadruplicity
5. Quintessence
6. ..... what comes after quintessence? I used to know the name but now I cannot remember and it isn't easily googleable.

Comment: I do not think these words mean what you think that they mean.

Comment: @TimLymington don't be triplicitous.

Comment: @TimLymington You said words plural. "Quintessence" and...?

Comment: @Avon: and *duplicity* (it's not hard to look up).  *Singularity* is also ambiguous.

Comment: @TimLymington Indeed it isn't. Did you? Duplicity definition 2. "the state of being double". Singularity definition 1. "the state... of being singular.

Comment: @Avon: I don't know about your dictionary, but Collins *only* has 'deception' (http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/duplicity), and the OED  has 'doubleness' only as a secondary meaning, marked 'literary'.

Comment: @TimLymington "only as a secondary **meaning**" I refer you to your initial comment. It is a meaning of the word. It is the word to use when you want to refer to the "state of being double" or do you have a better word for that?

Comment: One of these words is not like the others,
One of these words just doesn't belong,
Can you tell which word is not like the others
By the time I finish my song?

Did you guess which word was not like the others?
Did you guess which word just doesn't belong?
If you guessed *quintessence* is not like the others,
Then you're absolutely...right!
Adapted from Sesame Street *One of These Things*

Answer (score 3):

**Sextuplicity** I presume

from

**[sextuple](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=sextuple#q=sextuple&hl=en)**
adjective
1. consisting of six parts or things.
(Google)

But a [search for sextuplicity](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=sextuplicity) suggests it is a very archaic word.

I don't see why quintessence goes at number five. I'm pretty sure it should be quintuplicity.

**[quintessence](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=quintessence#q=quintessence+definition)**
noun
1. the most perfect or typical example of a quality or class.
2. a refined essence or extract of a substance.
(Google)

Presuming the "icity" is always logically constructed from the "tuple" then this wikipedia page would help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple